Executing intermediate signals in 1 clock cycle inside a clocked process in VHDL
Let's say I have a signal B that evaluates its value from signal A. It's messy to write the whole operation in one line so I would like to use an intermediate signal A_rounded (my actual code is a lot more compilcated than this, so I have to use intermediate stages).
A_rounded <= A + shift_left(to_signed(1, 32), 28-InputFracPart); 
B <= shift_right(A_rounded, 29-InputFracPart);

If I put these lines inside a clocked process:
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        A_rounded <= A + shift_left(to_signed(1, 32), 28-InputFracPart);
        B <= shift_right(A_rounded, 29-InputFracPart);
    end if;
end process;

It takes 2 cycles to compute the new value of B from A. But I want it to be 1.
The only way that I can think of reducing it down to 1 is take the intermediate step outside the process like this:
A_rounded <= A + shift_left(to_signed(1, 32), 28-InputFracPart);

process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        B <= shift_right(A_rounded, 29-InputFracPart);
    end if;
end process;

Is there another way of doing this while keeping the logic together inside the process?

You could factor out the calculation to a function.

A_rounded should be a variable, instead. In that case, the variable value gets assigned immediately with the intermediate value and effectively works as a substitute for the complex intermediate expression(s).
process(clk)
    variable A_rounded : signed;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        A_rounded := A + shift_left(to_signed(1, 32), 28-InputFracPart);
        B <= shift_right(A_rounded, 29-InputFracPart);
    end if;
end process;

